# Managing DTLS using a non-blocking architecture

Tags: java, netty, nio, bouncycastle, dtls

I am trying to add DTLS support in my server that is currently based on Netty. 
Netty gives me the possibility to add handlers to a pipeline where packets are treated in the defined order and changed when they need to be changed.

BouncyCastle's support for TLS and DTLS is currently limited to use with "old" blocking I/O. This makes it difficult (maybe impossible) to use BC with non-blocking NIO frameworks like Netty.

Does anyone know of any DTLS implementation that can be used with non-blocking frameworks like Netty or a possible workaround to make regular cryptography libraries such has Bouncy Castle work in this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/pull/96) for the Bouncy Castle library that implements DTLS using non-blocking API. You could apply it to the BC source code and create your own version of it.